# How do you register handlebars partials using browserify?

Tags: browserify, handlebars.js

I am using browserify to bundle javascript dependencies and [hbsfy](https://github.com/epeli/node-hbsfy) to compile handlebars templates. I want to use partials in my templates. However, in the [example project](https://github.com/epeli/node-hbsfy/blob/master/example/index.js), each partial that you use must be explicitly registered.

Ideally, I want to be able to "require" only the template in my view, without having to register each partial, because my views should not have to care about how the template is implemented. How do I implement this using browserify?